# use subdomain after authenticate user

Tags: laravel-5

in Laravel 5.1, how easy is it to redirect user after being authenticated to custom subdomain? example:

`{name}.domain.com`

most example on internet uses two laravel apps for main and subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subdomain routing to accomplish this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Then you can recieve the subdomain used in the requested URL and use it to customize content. This uses a single Laravel application.

Comment: do i have to configure anything on my nginx?